# VS 2003 and SourceSafe How to Add .vbproj.webinfo file to sourcesafe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

How to add .vbproj.webinfo file to sourcesafe? and 
This is my local folder:

[image: folder]

I want to add That file to sourcesafe.
But no option from visual studio to access that file.

[image: project]
Please help

Comment: You may open SourceSafe Explorer and try adding the file from there.

Comment: Yes, maybe you was correct.